# Freeswitch dialplan cURL - how to set a timeout

Tags: curl, freeswitch

I am trying to configure the FreeSWITCH dial-plan, what I am trying to achieve here is to get more information about the caller before connecting them to the agents by using an external web-service.
The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the web-service takes more time than usual to respond to the request. so it there a way to set a timeout on the dial-plan's cURL request?
Below is the XML configuration:

```html
<condition field="${IS_INTIME}" expression="true">
 <action inline="true" application="curl" data="https://test.com/service?caller_id_number=${caller_id_number}&token=123"/>
 <action application="set" data="IS_VIP=${curl_response_data}" inline="true"/>
</condition>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to include the XML configuration :)

Comment: Hello @Andy, Sorry mate, now I have edited my post and the XML is added.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mod_curl documentation](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_curl) syntax of curl command is following:

`curl url [headers|json|content-type <mime-type>|connect-timeout <seconds>|timeout <seconds>] [get|head|post|delete|put [data]]`

So try to use `data="https://test.com/service?caller_id_number=${caller_id_number}&token=123 timeout 60"/>`

Comment: Tried this actually, but it is still not working :(

Comment: did you try connect-timeout instead of timeout?